# Large HTML shows empty page (WSOD - White screen of death) - PHP

Tags: php, html, wsod

I am having a two dimensional PHP array which I need to iterate and show the array data in HTML controls. 
Array is huge (about 2500 rows and 25 columns for each row), it renders around 10MB web page (on my local system). But this do not display any thing on server and shows a blank page (WSOD - White screen of death). 
I have to show all data at once (no paging)
**post_max_size** and **upload_max_filesize** are set to 50M in **php.ini/.htaccess**, I have confirmed this using **phpinfo**
**max_execution_time** is 600 Seconds (10 minutes)

I have used

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

but no errors are displayed.

In apache Error log I am having Fatal Error **Allowed memory size of 210763776 bytes exhausted**, Its strange because it makes 200 MB? Why this is happening? Whats the solution?

What can be possible issue and solution?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Checked your php and your web server error logs?

Comment: Is there any errors log ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP's white screen of death](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death)

Comment: Have you verified that the large array is the problem by limiting the array size (while changing nothing else) and getting output successfully? What HTTP status code comes with the white screen response? Is it 500?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Array is absolutely fine as its working fine on my local system. Yes the HTTP status code is 500 with WSOD

Comment: In error log I am having Fatal Error **Allowed memory size of 210763776 bytes exhausted**, Its strange because it makes 200 MB? Why this is happening? Whats the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to increase memory_limit. It was set to 201 MB but still for this particular request it was not working. After I increased the memory_limit to 500MB the page started working properly.
I am not sure though that why 201MB memory_limit is not enough for my request. Also the change of memory_limit was not sufficient in php.ini so I had to change this in Plesk panel.